# React Redux Advanced Search in front-end

Tags: reactjs, search, redux, filter, lodash

I am trying a new web app like a movie, book,song search app
I have to do the search completely with react so my problem starts when I have to filter my array of data with filters.

Filter params are dynamic since user can search from Title or use advanced search forms for producer , year etc but those fields are not required.

So my params look like : query={title:"Larry"} or {title:"Larry", year:"2010",...}
Can I search in array dynamically with Lodash ? If yes , do I need to use forEach(query)and then for each value, key combination filter array?

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS has Array.filter method used like this:

```
myNumbers.filter(entry => entry.title === query.title && entry.year === query.year)
```

You get your elements that matches in your condition..